# ¿Cómo obtener el siguiente registro de una base de datos SQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una situación donde necesito consulto un un registro:

```
SELECT * from noticia WHERE ID = 12; --inicio el ID 12
```

Ese registro lo obtengo en una aplicación `JAVA`, y se que el registro que estoy manipulando es el **ID 12**, como podría consultar el próximo,
estaba probando sumarle 1 al **ID** actual pero en ocasiones no hay datos, puede ser que el registro 13 haya sido eliminado.

Comment: No has pensado en obtener una lista de todas las noticias? Select * FROM noticias. Puedes hasta paginar. Ahora, puedes crear una validación en JAVA si el ID consultado no retorna rows la consulta, no muestra nadas y sigue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener el registro cuyo **ID** es mayor a **12** en orden ascendente ("*el siguiente*"), podrías hacerlo así:

```
SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE ID > 12 ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Gracias! funciona

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer la columna ID es ascendente.  Si es asi, puedes obtener la ultima noticia asi:

```
SELECT * from noticia ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Ojo, no dijo que fuera la ultima.. pidio la siguiente

Comment: Si es la siguiente noticia, actualmente tengo la 12 y necesito ir por la siguiente que puede ser 13, 14,15 o un numero mayor